# Handle Koin in base fragment (Module already loaded error)

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, koin

I have a base fragment and 2 more fragments eg fragmentOne, fragmentTwo that extend the base fragment.

```
abstract class BaseFragment(): Fragment(){
    init{
        loadKoinModules(listOf(sampleModules))
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        unloadKoinModules(listOf(sampleModules))
    }
}
```

When I landed on fragmentOne, koin modules are loaded and everything is fine. I navigate from fragmentOne to fragmentTwo, loadKoinModules is called again before unloadKoinModules. I think the loaded modules in fragmentOne still exist and are not removed before loading the modules for fragmentTwo. What is the correct way or lifecycle to load and unload the koin modules?

```
module 'org.koin.core.module.Module@87380fe' already loaded!
module 'org.koin.core.module.Module@cef805f' already loaded!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### To fix it fast

```
abstract class BaseFragment(): Fragment(){
    init{
        // Making sure we do not get "module already loaded" error
        unloadKoinModules(listOf(sampleModules))
        loadKoinModules(listOf(sampleModules))
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        unloadKoinModules(listOf(sampleModules))
    }
}
```

There is no way around this because `init` called first, then `onCreateView` of Fragment2, then `onDestroyView` of Fragment1 (and not always it is called, depends on how Fragment2 is introduced to the stack of fragments).

Personally, I'd remove module loading from fragments. But I'm not sure why you need to unload them.

#### A slightly better way

What comes first to my mind is:

1. You create a new `Activity` based class;
2. Inside of this class from `onCreate` you load modules;
3. You show the fragments you need, navigate up and down the back stack of fragments of **this activity**;
4. When `Activity#onDestroy` is called - unload modules

```
class MyActivity: Activity {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        loadKoinModules(listOf(sampleModules))

        // load the first fragment
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        unloadKoinModules(listOf(sampleModules))
    }
}
```

#### How to do it better? (if unloading can be removed)

*First of all, make sure you really want to unload these modules. Why not have them loaded only once and leave? Decide for yourself as you see fit.*

Koin modules must be loaded only once. Once they are loaded these modules will be available throughout the application. It means you cannot load the same module twice - there is no need for it.

Amongst Koin official examples there is a one specifically for the Android:

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
  override fun onCreate(){
    super.onCreate()
    // start Koin!
    startKoin {
      // declare used Android context
      androidContext(this@MyApplication)
      // declare modules
      modules(myModule)
    }
  } 
}
```

As we can see modules are loaded from the `Application` class. You can have only one valid instance of `Application` class when your app is running. It means `onCreate` will not be called twice, so it is safe to load modules from `Application#onCreate`.

Alternatively, you can load modules from `onCreate` of your `Activity` class, as mentioned above. **But be aware that activity can be recreated multiple times during a lifecycle of the application.**

Comment: I am still learning Koin and your explanation is great. Does unloading unwanted koin modules improve the app performance? My thought was to load only whatever I need, unload them afterwards to save memory. If I am wrong or that doesn't impact a lot, maybe I should just load everything in the application class and leave it.

Comment: "unloading  unwanted koin modules improve the app performance" - it can. Depends on the size of the modules. In any case, it frees some memory. The intention of yours is actually a good one but I think it is an overhead in case your app is small or not utilizing much of the resources available. A few modules will not harm performance. I'd unload modules if: they are used rarely and/or are cheap to create and I need this extra memory. If you need to download a few MBs of data before a module can be stored in Koin - you should not remove it, IMHO. Each case should be studied.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I will redesign my app as needed.